# Inputting formatted IRC text in Pidgin

Tags: text-formatting, irc, pidgin

What plugin or software is available to use [**Pidgin**](https://pidgin.im/)'s native text formatting system to allow **IRC messages** to be **sent with formatted text**?

[image: [Screenshot of Pidgin with an IRC chat open]]

Comment: Same issue here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me with [pidgin-irc-format](https://github.com/BlueWinds/pidgin-irc-format).

You have to build it and need at least `pkg-config`, `pidgin-dev` and `gcc`.

You might have to use this (2 lines, 6 characters) patch: https://github.com/UMLAUTaxl/pidgin-irc-format/pull/1/commits/c8a723eaeaba243db652b7297788d5e80405172d

Comment: [It's a start!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV0vh.png) The plugin follows some of the [IRC formatting conventions](https://web.archive.org/web/20191218101724/https://modern.ircdocs.horse/formatting.html). Bold, underline, and italics work fine. Color codes sent have to match the exact hex representation coded into the plugin. Strikethrough and monospace are not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

[From the official Pidgin web site](http://www.pidgin.im/download/ubuntu/)

```
To setup the PPA, follow these steps: 
1. Click to download the Pidgin PPA package.
2. Select Open with: and GDebi Package Installer. Click OK.
3. Click Install Package.
4. Click Close. Then close GDebi.

After doing this, check for and apply updates: 
1. Click System, point to Administration, and click Update Manager.
2. Click Check.
3. Click Install Updates.
```

That helped me, hope that will help you as well.

Give it a try.

Comment: These were instructions to update Pidgin to the latest PPA version but [an updated Pidgin does not add IRC formatting functionality](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ChangeLog) and the [PPA is considered deprecated](https://launchpad.net/~pidgin-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).